# How to add v-model to button of a child componen and bind on it in the parent component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-component

`i am using vue3 with options api`

as shown in the code posted below, in `NotifDimsToLSRIncomformability` component, i have a button. and `NotifDimsToLSRIncomformability` is being hosted in a parent component as shown
in the code posted below.

i would like listen to the button clicks of `NotifDimsToLSRIncomformability` in the parent component. or in other words, what i want to achieve is, when the button is clicked, i want
to listen to these clicks in the parent/hosting component and achieve some side effects based on the clickability of that button.

my attempts are:
i introduced the directive `v-model` to the button and bind to it on the parent/hosting component as shown below, but that does not work

plase let me know how can i bind on the clickability of the button in the parent/hosting component

**hosting-component**

```
<template>
<NotifDimsToLSRIncomformability
    v-bind:showNotifDimsToLSRIncomformability="showNotifDimsToLSRIncomformability"
    v-model:vModel="vModel"  //<<<<==========================HERE
></NotifDimsToLSRIncomformability>
```

**NotifDimsToLSRIncomformability**
**button**

```
<cds-button 
    class="clsBtnClosePosition"
    action="primary"
    status="primary"
    size="md"
    type="button"
    v-model="vModel"//<<<<==========================HERE
    @click="onCloseNotification()"
> X
</cds-button>
```

explained in the question above

Answer (score 0):

Inside function `onCloseNotification` in the child (you should remove the braces after the name - event handlers don't need braces unless you want to call them immediately and use the result of the function as an event handler - rather than the function itself) add the following line:

```js
this.$emit('click');
```

Then in the parent component, handle the `click` event from the child component

```html
<NotifDimsToLSRIncomformability
    v-bind:showNotifDimsToLSRIncomformability="showNotifDimsToLSRIncomformability"
    v-model:vModel="vModel"
    @click="onButtonClicked"  //<<<<==========================HERE
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the provide/inject feature. Each change on the provided variable, injected in the child component, can easily lead to side effect in the parent component.

Comment: what if i provided a value equal to, lets say 'x' twice, will it be injected twice as well or only once?

Comment: There will be one value ‘x’, available in the parent and the children. If the value is reactive, you can make any change in the children and keep it in the parent